# Datetime column manipulation and making a new column in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe containing a date column and amount column. Date column consists of hour and date information. For each day there are 24 entries for each hour of the day. I need to create a new column that shows the amount that belongs to 24 hours prior to the date and time for that row.

For example for "2019-11-06 18:00:00", the new column should show the amount info for "2019-11-05 18:00:00". The problem is what we should do with the first entry since it has no prior dates. I'm thinking I can remove the first entry when I create the new column but for now I'm getting KeyError since the first entry does not have a prior date. How to go around the KeyError?

What the dataframe looks like: [screenshot of dataframe](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/11/8/7ec897a27647c38102456418e33fbf59-full.png)

**[in]:**

```py
hours24_c = df["Date"]-timedelta(hours=24)
df["hours24"] = df["amount"].loc[hours24_c]
```

**[out]:**

```
KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2015-12-30 00:00:00', '2015-12-30 01:00:00',\n               '2015-12-30 02:00:00', '2015-12-30 03:00:00',\n               '2015-12-30 04:00:00', '2015-12-30 05:00:00',\n               '2015-12-30 06:00:00', '2015-12-30 07:00:00',\n               '2015-12-30 08:00:00', '2015-12-30 09:00:00',\n               ...\n               '2019-11-05 14:00:00', '2019-11-05 15:00:00',\n               '2019-11-05 16:00:00', '2019-11-05 17:00:00',\n               '2019-11-05 18:00:00', '2019-11-05 19:00:00',\n               '2019-11-05 20:00:00', '2019-11-05 21:00:00',\n               '2019-11-05 22:00:00', '2019-11-05 23:00:00'],\n              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=33744, freq=None)] are in the [index]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by date and then use shift:

```
df.sort_values(by = "Date", inplace = True)
df["hours24"] = df["amount"].shift(24)
```

Comment: what if I want to shift by 2 weeks? or 3 months?

Comment: change the shift number to 14*24 for two weeks. For 3-months is similar.

Comment: do you suggest any method for dealing with N/A values resulting from the shift?

Comment: what are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: Time Series Forecasting with linear regression

Comment: you want to use what variables as independent and what as outcome?

Comment: hours_24 is the independent variable and amount is the outcome. So I need to build a model using amount 24 hours prior to that date and real amount will be target value I'd like to predict

Comment: you want to use the past as an independent variable? linear regression is not a good method for timeseries. You probably want ARIMA

Comment: Yes I think I will use that too later in the assignment, but this part of the task is asked specifically to use linear regression. I'm asked to use past values as features then compare accuracy based on the actual values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202103/discussion-between-aprilangel-and-moli).